# Считывание строки до пробела Си

Tags: c

Необходимо считать строку до пробела.
Использую функцию форматированного ввода scanf_s(...), но если вводимая строка имеет длину меньшую, чем передаваемую в качестве третьего аргумента, то строка забивается мусором далее
т.е.

```
//MAX_WORD_LEN = 128
char word[MAX_WORD_LEN];
printf("Enter word : \n");
scanf_s("%s", &word, MAX_WORD_LEN);
```

Ввод :abc

Содержимое word :abcюююююююююююююююююююююююююююююююююююююююююююююююююююююююююююю

Comment: Интересно, кто придумывает такие *отские задания?

Comment: @0andriy, это побочная задача. Я пишу толковый словарь, столкнулся с проблемой - решил спросить, потому что на Си пишу очень мало и с майкрософтскими функциями вообще не знаком.

Comment: Это не Си. Это частная функция некоторой библиотеки.

Comment: @0andriy, не буду сейчас разводить здесь демагогию. Нужно разобраться с тем, как это работает.

Comment: Ну не знаю, почитайте что ли документацию: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx

Comment: *"Использую функцию форматированного ввода"* -- используйте мозг.

Comment: @PinkTux , как остроумно :). Но все-таки, я пишу на языке Си совсем мало и поэтому написал сюда за помощью

Comment: Ваш код вполне корректно работает в VC++2015, например. У вас *точно* есть ошибка? `int main()
{
    char word[MAX_WORD_LEN];
    printf("Enter word : \n");
    scanf_s("%s", &word, MAX_WORD_LEN);
    printf("[%s]\n",word);
}`
все нормально. Как вы вообще проверяете, что у вас в `word`?

Comment: @Harry смотрю через отладчик

Comment: А попробуйте-ка вывести посимвольно - простите уж за глупое предположение, но, может, вы там в отладчике этот нулик просто не замечаете? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char word[MAX_WORD_LEN] = {0};
```

Comment: Отлично, в документации сказано, что `\n` относится к классу пробельных (white-space) символов, почему же `scanf_s()` не терминирует нулём?